# Google API not returning name and people scope is invalid

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, google-api, google-oauth, google-api-php-client

I am using OAuth2.0 to connect to Google and trying to get the user details. I am getting email id , etc. But I am not able to get the name and other data from the access_token which I receive.

Currently I am using `scopes - 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me','email'`.

I know there is a scope `https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me` but when I use this, I get invalid scope error. However , I manually access https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me?access_token=# then it works just fine. But through the API it is not working :(

Any leads ?

I am instantiating the `$client` as `new Google_Client();` by using the Google Api for PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `profile` and `email` as scopes, `https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me` is not a scope, it's an API.

[For your reference](https://developers.google.com/+/api/oauth).